# Wrong result after multiple read

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I was wondering i someone could help me with my code, i want to read more than one time from the stdin in x86 but when i read the second time, it is ignoring the number and just add the 50. I want it to work so that i can call it as many times as i need to go adding the register EAX by an arbitrary number (which i will load from variables A,B,etc later on)

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
  call leer
  call atoi
  add eax,10
  call itoa

  call imprimir
  call limpiar

  call leer
  call atoi
  add eax,50
  call itoa
  call imprimir

  jmp salir

;-----------ATOI
atoi:
    mov esi,Buffer ;move buffer address
    mov eax,0 ;where im going to keep result
    mov ebx,0 ;where i put char

.atoi_start:
    mov bl, byte[esi] ;get the char
    je .end_atoi
    cmp bl, '0' ;check if null
    jb .end_atoi
    cmp bl,'9'
    ja .end_atoi
    imul eax,10 ;multiplico resultado por 10
    sub bl,0x30 ;ascii->int
    add eax,ebx ;agegue el nuevo digito
    inc esi ;getting ready for next char
    jmp .atoi_start
.end_atoi:
    ret ;at this point i have int representation in eax


;-----------ITOA
itoa:
    mov ebx, eax ;mueve el numero en eax a ebx
    mov esi, Buffer
    mov ebx,10
    add esi,10
.itoa2:
    xor edx,edx
    div ebx 
    add dl,'0' ;lo convierte en char
    mov [esi],dl
    dec esi
    test eax,eax
    jnz .itoa2
    jz .doneItoa

.doneItoa:
    ret


;----------------------LIMPIAR
limpiar:
    ;limpia buffer usando eax
    xor eax,eax;
    xor edx,edx
    xor ecx,ecx

    mov ecx, 1100 ;tamano de veces que voy a limpiar
    lea edx, [Buffer] ;direccion inicial del buffer

.loop:
    mov [edx+ecx],eax ;voy a limpiar de atras para adelante
    dec ecx ;decremento contador y verifico si es 0 para seguir limiando
    jnz .loop
    ret

imprimir:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,Buffer
    mov edx,1100 ;tamano
    int 0x80 ;syscall

;ahora imprimo nueva linea
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,nuevaLinea
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80
    ret

leer:
    ;vamos a poner el msg en pantalla
    mov eax,4 ;sys_write
    mov ebx,1 ;stdout
    mov ecx,msg ;paso el mensaje
    mov edx,lenMsg ;paso el largo del mensaje
    int 80h

    ;ahora leemos
    mov eax,3 ;sys_read
    mov ebx,2 ;stdin
    mov ecx,Buffer
    mov edx,1100
    int 80h
    ret

salir:
    mov rax,60 ;sys_exit
    mov rdi,0 ;codigo de salida
    syscall


section .data
   msg db 'Ingrese un numero: '
   lenMsg equ $-msg

   nuevaLinea db 10;nueva linea
   A dq 0


section .bss    
    Buffer: resb 1100

    B: resb 1100
```

Comment: fd `2` is not `stdin` that's `stderr`. No telling what that will do if you try to read from it. `stdin` is fd `0`.

Comment: `cmp bl, '0' ;check if null` does not check for null.  A null is `0` not `'0'`.

Answer (score 2):

In atoi, the fifth instruction

```
    je .end_atoi
```

tests the Z flag which has not been set in this function. So it is jumping based on the value of Z from whatever happened before atoi is called, which is the read system call in leer.

Either put

```
    test bl, bl
```

before that je instruction or just remove the je, since the end of string will be caught by the cmp '0' that follows.

But that's not a complete fix: The read system call doesn't null terminate the input. Leer should use the number of bytes read (returned by the read system call) to place a null byte in the buffer after the input.